# Select subset of dataframe from intersection of two sets

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, set

I've got two sets of column headers from a DataFrame. One set is a subset of the other one.

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'feature1':[1,2,3], 'feature2':[3,4,5], 'feature3':[6,7,8]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

now I got two sets:

```
set_1 = {'feature1','feature2','feature3'}
set_2 = {'feature1','feature3'}
```

How can I achieve that in my (new) Dataframe just the columns from the subset are selected?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sets are not hashable, so you need to convert them to a list, for example.

Then you can select the dataframe like this

```
df[list(set_1)]
```

which returns

```
    feature1    feature3    feature2
0   1   6   3
1   2   7   4
2   3   8   5
```

or

```
df[list(set_2)]
```

which returns

```
    feature1    feature3
0   1   6
1   2   7
2   3   8
```